# Representing environment variable 10

Tags: shell

I am passing parameters from Java program to shell script for which I am using environment variables in shell script to receive the parameters. I am able to get parameters till no 9 by using $9. But I am getting an error if I get the 10th parameter. I am using ${10} to get the input of the 10 th parameter. Am I going wrong some where .

Comment: What is the **exact error** message you get?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the `${10}` format although it does seem sensible. However, you can use the `shift` builtin function to reuse `$1`. Something like so.

```
#!/bin/sh

a=$1
shift
b=$1

echo "$a:$b"
```

And you can run it like so.

```
noufal@sanitarium% ~/foo.sh Hello Goodbye
Hello:Goodbye
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But I am passing about 15 parameters to shell so $1 may represent the first parameter that I sent rite

Comment: Yes but the order is relevant is it not? So you will be able to put a block that gets the value and then shifts repeatedly for all 15 of your values before processing starts.

Comment: If you have non trivial argument passing, you should use `getopts` anyway.